git rebase is stuck in "Enumerating objects: 1, done" loop
I have a feature branch feature and a develop branch. In the feature branch, I ran git rebase develop, but I got stuck in a very strange loop:
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1/1), 4.39 KiB | 408.00 KiB/s, done.
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1/1), 4.39 KiB | 449.00 KiB/s, done.
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1/1), 4.40 KiB | 500.00 KiB/s, done.
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.

The loop never ends, and it is definitely not the correct behaviour for rebase. Anyone has any clue what is happening?

Did you upgrade recently to Git 2.47.0? It's known to has problems.

@phd No, it's still at 2.46
